# Trying to update a list on one form from second form

Tags: c#

I'm a first semester c# student and trying to learn over summer break to be ahead when school starts back up in the fall.
I have a multiform application that I'm using lists to store information and statistics.
On form one I have a list that stores a bowler's name. This form is called MainForm.  On the second form, opened from a button on MainForm, I have two text boxes for first name and last name and an 'add bowler' button.
 I want to be able to input the information in the text boxes and have this update the list that I created on MainForm. 
The second form is called AddBowlerForm. I've been working on this for a couple of days, and I've followed so many tutorials and youtube videos that I'm almost lost on where I started.

The code I have at the moment on MainForm:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create list to hold names of bowlers
        List<string> listBowlers = new List<string>();

        ReadBowlers(listBowlers);
        DisplayBowlers(listBowlers);
    }
private void buttonAddBowler_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create instance of AddBowlerForm
        AddBowlerForm addBowler = new AddBowlerForm(this);
        if (addBowler.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            listBowlers.items.add(addBowler.Bowler());
            listBoxBowlers.Items.Add(AddBowlerForm.Bowler());

        }

        //Display the form.
        addBowler.ShowDialog();
```

---

The relevant code from AddBowlerForm:

```
public AddBowlerForm(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mainForm = mainForm;

    }
    public string Bowler
    {
        get
        {
            return textBoxFirstName.Text + textBoxLastName.Text;
        }
    }
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

    }
```

I truly would appreciate any and all help on this. I've read more web pages in the last couple of days than I can remember, but not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need something called a Handler.

A handler is like a promise that is given to an object, which says "When you call this method, there will be one to handle it" even when the method doing the handling is completely out of scope from the object invoking the handler.

So, your NewBowler form needs to include in its constructor a delegate which points back to a method which requires the input you need. So, when you click the submit button on your form, the method that button calls will raise the "NewBowlerHandler()" event which you provided in the constructor.

Then, whatever method back on your MainForm which actually does the adding of the bowler will handle the input provided by the form.

If you need more resources on delegates, handlers, and event, you can find documentation here [EventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=netframework-4.8) [Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to do something that is over my head. Although I can barely understand the content of this information I'm still grasping for some sort of example to solve my problem. Perhaps I bit off more than I can chew and need to find another solution to my problem.